# How to change hair color along absolute value of hair strand length?

Tags: hair, color

I know what I can get using "Hair Info" node's "Intercept" value with "Color Ramp" node. The thing is, it's really unrealistic when I have hair of various length. I want melanin value to be affected by total hair length value, not it's % to simulate hair that are burned brighter with sun. Is there any trick to do that? Like somehow intercepting only the longest hair value and using it for every strand?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

how to make this happen: you need Geometry node -> separate RGB -> Map Range -> ColorRamp -> output.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it's not. It's mapped to Z axis of the whole object and that's it, it's not mapped to hair length.